# Counting, adding and averaging from a list in Python

Tags: python

Ten numbers are to be read in from the keyboard.  After this write how many of these numbers were positive, the total of these positive numbers, and the mean (average) of the positive numbers.

This is what I have so far

```
print ("Input 10 numbers, separated by commas")

k=[x for x in input("Enter number:").split(',')]

for l in k:
    print (l)
    if l > 0:
        print("positive")
    else:
        print("negative")
```

However I have no idea where to go and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Please add more detail on what exactly it is that you're after (ie, is something broken, is there something you don't know how to do, etc).  Also, please provide code for attempts you have made to do this yourself.  SO is not a codewriting service ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an adequate solution:

```
num_list = []

for i in range(10):
    num = input("Enter number:")
    num_list.append(int(num))

positives = 0
pos_nums = []

for num in num_list:
    if num > 0:
        positives += 1
        pos_nums.append(num)

pos_sum = sum(pos_nums)

print(positives)
print(pos_sum)
print(pos_sum/positives)
```

Comment: Great!  if an answer works for you, you are supposed to 'accept the answer'

Comment: I have no idea how to do that haha sorry

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Ah okie I see it!

Answer (score 0):

You can define two variables `positive_total` and `positive_count` to keep track, while going through the list

```
print ("Input 10 numbers, separated by commas")

k=[x for x in input("Enter number:").split(',')]

positive_total = 0 #total of all positive integers
positive_count = 0 #keeps count of number of positive integers
for l in k:
    print (l)
    if l > 0:
        positive_total += l
        positive_count += 1
        print("positive")
    else:
        print("negative")

print('Count of positive integers = {}'.format(positive_count))
print('Total of positive integers = {}'.format(positive_total))
print('Average of positive integers = {}'.format(positive_total/positive_count))
```

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Problem 3.py", line 3, in <module>
    for l in k:
NameError: name 'k' is not defined"

Comment: @mememan9001 i did not include the first two lines of your code. Just added them. please check